# Counting occurrences of specific letters in string

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a string that looks like this:

```
3x3x3x204x4x4x6f
```

I want to read these letters in a row and want to count the amount of times I see the same pattern. For instance, I see that 3x happens 3 times. I want my counter to then reset and start from the position it ended on and if it sees a pattern again like the one above, give me count of repetitions.

I have tried this with no luck (I'm reading 2 characters at a time):

```
foreach (var set in splitString)
{
    currChars = set;

    if (!currChars.Contains(prevChars))
    {
        if (!currChars.Contains(_prevchars))
        {

        }
        newSet.Add(_prevchar);
        newSet.Add(occurrenceCount.ToString());
        newSet.Add("x");

        occurrenceCount = 0;
        newSet.Add(currChars);
    }
    else
    {
        occurrenceCount = occurrenceCount + 2;
        _prevchar = MethodX.StringManipulation.TruncateLongString(prevChars, 1);
        _prevchars = currChars;
    }
    prevChars = currChars;
}
```

Comment: What should the correct output look like? Also, when you say that you're "having no luck", can you explain what exactly your program is currently doing, and why it's not correct?

Comment: Do you need a suffix tree?

Answer (score 2):

Without using Regex, you can use the overload of [`String.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7cct0x33.aspx) which accepts a starting position parameter. For every ocurrence of the pattern you find, increment the position accordingly and search again.

```
string s = "3x3x3x204x4x4x6f";
string pattern = "3x";
int count = 0;
int pos = 0;
while (true)
{
    int index = s.IndexOf(pattern, pos);
    if (index == -1) break;
    count++;
    pos = index + pattern.Length;       
}

    //count == 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var repeatList=Regex.Matches(input,@"(.+)(\1)+")
                .Cast<Match>()
                .Select(x=>
                   new { 
                        name = x.Groups[1].Value, 
                        count = x.Groups[2].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Count()+1 
                       }
                       );
```

You can now iterate

```
foreach(var repeat in repeatList)
{
    repeat.name;
    repeat.count;
}
```